# How can I extract the rows with overlapping time using sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, time, overlap

I have a table in sql which contains the data series of 3 years. But the start and end times of each year are not exactly the same. How can I extract the data series of the 3 years which completely overlap?

for example my table is as follow:

| id | Date _time | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-11-30 00:0:00 | ---- |
| 1 | . | ---- |
| . | . | ---- |
| . | . | ---- |
| 1 | 2020-12-10 23:00:00 | ---- |
| 2 | 2018-12-01 04:00:00 | ---- |
| . | . | ---- |
| 2 | 2018-12-20 20:00:00 | ---- |
| . | . | ---- |
| . | . | ---- |
| 10000 | 2019-11-15 06:00:00 | ---- |
| . | . | ---- |
| 10000 | 2019-12-07 04:00:00 | ---- |
| . | . | ---- |
| . | . | ---- |

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results so it is clear what data you are working with and what you want to accomplish.

Comment: it is edited know @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly beginning and end of each year can be different and you want only overlapped records in all years, if yes here is one way :

```
;with cte as (
SELECT 
   right(min(date_time)::varchar,14) min_date
 , right(max(date_time)::varchar,14) max_date
from tablename
group by date_trunc('year',date_time)
)
SELECT tablename.*
FROM tablename
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
     MAX(min_date) MIN_OVP 
   , MIN(max_date) MAX_OVP 
  FROM CTE
) DOV
ON  right(date_time::varchar,14) >= MIN_OVP
AND right(date_time::varchar,14) <= MAX_OVP
```

so I'm trying to  remove the year from datetime column so I can find the overlapping month/day hour:min:sec in each year.then compare it to filter out non overlapped data.
probably not the best solution but should work.